# Can I resume training of my neural network in Keras? (Without saving, just in the next cell of Jupyter)

Tags: keras

I've trained my model on 30 epochs. I just want continue training. I didn't save model state. Its state is saved in object. Can I just fit my NN in the next cell and continue training safely like on the picture? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, successive calls to fit will incrementally train the model
keras github issue [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4446)

Comment: Can I resume safely train but with different batch_size?